# Comparison between different unsupervised learning algorithms

Tags: python, scikit-learn, metrics, unsupervised-learning

I am working on a project on binary classification, where I have to test several unsupervised learning algorithms, like: `Isolation Forest`, `OneClassSVM`, `Local Outlier Factor` and `Elliptic Envelope`. After fitting and predicting with those models I get the new binary labels. Out of 1000 data points: `Isolation Forest`, `Local Outlier Factor` and `Elliptic Envelope` predict only 10 points belonging to class 1 and the rest to class 0; on the other hand, `OneClassSVM` predicts 872 points belonging to class 1 and the rest to class 0.

I am wondering:

1. How reliable are these results?
2. How could I measure which algorithm did the best job at predicting?

Comment: How much dimensions your data consist of?

Comment: This blog post may help you https://medium.com/balabit-unsupervised/how-to-evaluate-unsupervised-anomaly-detection-for-user-behavior-analytics-88f3d5de2018

Comment: @moeassal the shape is 3000 rows and 25 columns